# changing camera to thunderbolt display for google hangout

Tags: camera, thunderbolt-display, google

I use google hangouts for multiple-people video calls, but it never detects the camera in the Thunderbolt display. It keeps using the camera on my MacBook Pro.

Is there any way to change the camera used in Hangouts if I want to use the Thunderbolt display's camera?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Click the **Options** button at the bottom of your chat list.
> 2. Select **Chat settings…** from the menu.
> 3. Adjust the selections in the drop-down menus for your camera, microphone, and speakers.

<sup>Source: https://support.google.com/chat/answer/162176</sup>

---

[alternative]

**June 2015** (latest)

Within a particular Hangout, you can know click on the Settings button at the top

[image: Settings button]

and change your audio and video settings.

[image: Within-Hangout options for audio and video]

This allows you to switch between the laptop's camera and the display's camera.

**February 2014** (possibly outdated)

By clicking on Options in the Hangouts app in Chrome:

[image]

the only thing I could see was:

[image: Hangouts options]

which didn't take me very far. So you can click on Gmail > Chat list > Chat settings:

[image]

Or go to Gmail > Settings > Chat [Note: this only worked for me (on Chrome) if I didn't have the new Hangouts list in Gmail, but rather the "old chat" interface. With the new Hangouts list, I'm still not sure how to go about it since the Chat options seems limited to "Chat on" or "Chat off".]

[image]

In any case, both of  Gmail > Chat list > Chat settings and Gmail > Settings > Chat take you to the same place, where you can select which camera to use.

[image: Gmail chat list > Options > Settings]